# How to mail the form details using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, gmail-api

I am maiking a contact-us page where i need on clicking on send button the text in message box to be mailed on my mail-id.

```
<section id="contact">

    <div class="container">

        <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="toyousender.php">

        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="NAME" required>

        <input  type="email" name="email" placeholder="MAIL" required>

        <textarea name="comments" placeholder="MESSAGE" required ></textarea>

        <button name="send" type="submit" class="submit">SEND</button>

     </form>

  </div>
</section>
```

I have tried below code for refrence :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gmail API demo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <style>
      iframe {
        width: 100%;
        border: 0;
        min-height: 80%;
        height: 600px;
        display: flex;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Gmail API demo</h1>

      <a href="#compose-modal" data-toggle="modal" id="compose-button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right hidden">Compose</a>

      <button id="authorize-button" class="btn btn-primary hidden">Authorize</button>

      <table class="table table-striped table-inbox hidden">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Date/Time</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="compose-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Compose</h4>
          </div>
          <form onsubmit="return sendEmail();">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="compose-to" placeholder="To" required />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject" required />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-message" placeholder="Message" rows="10" required></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" id="send-button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="reply-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Reply</h4>
          </div>
          <form onsubmit="return sendReply();">
            <input type="hidden" id="reply-message-id" />

            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reply-to" disabled />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control disabled" id="reply-subject" disabled />
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="reply-message" placeholder="Message" rows="10" required></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="submit" id="reply-button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var clientId = '63283744103-gsdvcbod7vg5mlc39mgfq3h171hrolk2.apps.googleusercontent.com';

      var apiKey = 'AIzaSyBXSp2nC5aiOoSS30_Z-sWybEUorGJPt2Y';
      // var scopes = ['https://mail.google.com/', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels'];
      var scopes =
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly ',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose']

      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
        window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
      }

      function checkAuth() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
          client_id: clientId,
          scope: scopes,
          immediate: true
        }, handleAuthResult);
      }

      function handleAuthClick() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
          client_id: clientId,
          scope: scopes,
          immediate: false
        }, handleAuthResult);
        return false;
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if(authResult && !authResult.error) {
          loadGmailApi();
          $('#authorize-button').remove();
          $('.table-inbox').removeClass("hidden");
          $('#compose-button').removeClass("hidden");
        } else {
          $('#authorize-button').removeClass("hidden");
          $('#authorize-button').on('click', function(){
            handleAuthClick();
          });
        }
      }

      function loadGmailApi() {
        gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', displayInbox);
      }

      function displayInbox() {
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
          'userId': 'me',
          'labelIds': 'INBOX',
          'maxResults': 10
        });
        request.execute(function(response) {
          $.each(response.messages, function() {
            var messageRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
              'userId': 'me',
              'id': this.id
            });
            messageRequest.execute(appendMessageRow);
          });
        });
      }

      function appendMessageRow(message) {
        $('.table-inbox tbody').append(
          '<tr>\
            <td>'+getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'From')+'</td>\
            <td>\
              <a href="#message-modal-' + message.id +
                '" data-toggle="modal" id="message-link-' + message.id+'">' +
                getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Subject') +
              '</a>\
            </td>\
            <td>'+getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Date')+'</td>\
          </tr>'
        );
        var reply_to = (getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Reply-to') !== '' ?
          getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Reply-to') :
          getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'From')).replace(/\"/g, '&quot;');

        var reply_subject = 'Re: '+getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Subject').replace(/\"/g, '&quot;');
        $('body').append(
          '<div class="modal fade" id="message-modal-' + message.id +
              '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">\
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">\
              <div class="modal-content">\
                <div class="modal-header">\
                  <button type="button"\
                          class="close"\
                          data-dismiss="modal"\
                          aria-label="Close">\
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>\
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">' +
                    getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Subject') +
                  '</h4>\
                </div>\
                <div class="modal-body">\
                  <iframe id="message-iframe-'+message.id+'" srcdoc="<p>Loading...</p>">\
                  </iframe>\
                </div>\
                <div class="modal-footer">\
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>\
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary reply-button" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reply-modal"\
                  onclick="fillInReply(\
                    \''+reply_to+'\', \
                    \''+reply_subject+'\', \
                    \''+getHeader(message.payload.headers, 'Message-ID')+'\'\
                    );"\
                  >Reply</button>\
                </div>\
              </div>\
            </div>\
          </div>'
        );
        $('#message-link-'+message.id).on('click', function(){
          var ifrm = $('#message-iframe-'+message.id)[0].contentWindow.document;
          $('body', ifrm).html(getBody(message.payload));
        });
      }

      function sendEmail()
      {
        $('#send-button').addClass('disabled');

        sendMessage(
          {
            'To': $('#compose-to').val(),
            'Subject': $('#compose-subject').val()
          },
          $('#compose-message').val(),
          composeTidy
        );

        return false;
      }

      function composeTidy()
      {
        $('#compose-modal').modal('hide');

        $('#compose-to').val('');
        $('#compose-subject').val('');
        $('#compose-message').val('');

        $('#send-button').removeClass('disabled');
      }

      function sendReply()
      {
        $('#reply-button').addClass('disabled');

        sendMessage(
          {
            'To': $('#reply-to').val(),
            'Subject': $('#reply-subject').val(),
            'In-Reply-To': $('#reply-message-id').val()
          },
          $('#reply-message').val(),
          replyTidy
        );

        return false;
      }

      function replyTidy()
      {
        $('#reply-modal').modal('hide');

        $('#reply-message').val('');

        $('#reply-button').removeClass('disabled');
      }

      function fillInReply(to, subject, message_id)
      {
        $('#reply-to').val(to);
        $('#reply-subject').val(subject);
        $('#reply-message-id').val(message_id);
      }

      function sendMessage(headers_obj, message, callback)
      {
        var email = '';

        for(var header in headers_obj)
          email += header += ": "+headers_obj[header]+"\r\n";

        email += "\r\n" + message;

        var sendRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
          'userId': 'me',
          'resource': {
            'raw': window.btoa(email).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
          }
        });

        return sendRequest.execute(callback);
      }

      function getHeader(headers, index) {
        var header = '';
        $.each(headers, function(){
          if(this.name.toLowerCase() === index.toLowerCase()){
            header = this.value;
          }
        });
        return header;
      }

      function getBody(message) {
        var encodedBody = '';
        if(typeof message.parts === 'undefined')
        {
          encodedBody = message.body.data;
        }
        else
        {
          encodedBody = getHTMLPart(message.parts);
        }
        encodedBody = encodedBody.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/\s/g, '');
        return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(encodedBody)));
      }

      function getHTMLPart(arr) {
        for(var x = 0; x <= arr.length; x++)
        {
          if(typeof arr[x].parts === 'undefined')
          {
            if(arr[x].mimeType === 'text/html')
            {
              return arr[x].body.data;
            }
          }
          else
          {
            return getHTMLPart(arr[x].parts);
          }
        }
        return '';
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but its gives an authorization error as in below image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTUP9.png)

Answer (score 3):

So the error literally explains what the problem is. You haven't authorised your mailer to send emails to/on behalf of you!

Also oddly enough you've got a commented variable for dealing with scopes, that seems to actually contain the scope you are looking for
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send`

I'd suggest you read up on authorization scopes.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes

From the google documentation:
"Publicly available applications with access to certain user data must pass review. If you see an access error for your app, submit a request using our [OAuth Developer Verification form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification).